# How can i delete message after entering command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there a way after you enter command like mine is -say now something,
is there way to it delete my message and leave only discord bot answer.

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class SayCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('say', 'fun', []);
  }

async  run(client, message, args) {
    const messageToSay = args.join(" ");
    const sayEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle("Mudra osoba ima nesto da kaze!")
       .setDescription(`${messageToSay}`)
       .setFooter(message.author.tag ,message.author.displayAvatarURL())
       .setColor("#5808ab")
       .setTimestamp();
      try {
        await message.channel.send(sayEmbed);
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          message.channel.send("JA ZIVKOVIC SLOBODAN NE SMEM TO DA KAZEM");
        }
      }

  }
```

What i want to say is like:
Me : -say Something
bot : repeat that but to delete my message up! Just to leave his

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code sample contains [message.delete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) which will remove the message (user's input).

```
        try {
            await message.channel.send(sayEmbed);
            message.delete(); //removes user's input message.
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            message.channel.send("JA ZIVKOVIC SLOBODAN NE SMEM TO DA KAZEM");
        }
```